# Periodic solution of autonomous system

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP $x' = f(x)$ ; $x(0) = x_0$ , where $f$ belong $C^1[E,R^2]$, $E$ belong $R^2$ is an open set. Suppose that the IVP has a periodic solution $z(t)$ which encloses a set  $K$ belong E. Show that all solutions of IVP with $x_0$ belong $K$ exist on $R$.

How I can the periodicity to prove the solution is bounded?

Comment: Done. Your turn.